# Handling key-value pair in JQuery for charting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, echarts

I have an ageband which I am generating with PHP from my database. The output is JSON-encoded and returned to my jQuery function.

The data returned looks like this:

```
{"result":{"20 - 29":"22","30 - 39":"78","40 - 49":"74","50 - 59":"71","60 - 69":"67","70 & Older":"0","Not Filled In (NULL)":"0"},"errors":false}
```

I am fetching this data using AJAX/jQuery:

```
if(!response.errors && response.result) {

}
```

The key is the age-range, so for example, ages 20-19: 22 people etc.

Anyway, I am trying to use the data to create a pie-chart, i'm using echarts (https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts/index-en.html)

The data format with sample data looks like this:

```
data: [{ value: 12, name: 'Moto Z' },{ value: 618, name: 'Galaxy S7 Edge' }]
```

I want my data to show like this:

```
data: [{ value: 22, name: '20-29' },{ value: 78, name: '30-39' }... etc]
```

How can I use my returned data with this chart?

Comment: Rebuild your data to proper format on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your object.

```
var data = []
$.each( result, function( key, value ) {
  data.push({ value: value, name: key })
});
```

Result is the contents of the result object in your Ajax response.
The new 'data' variable should be formatted per your needs.

Comment: thanks, but this returns the following: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using another external library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) then:

```
var data = _( _.pairs( json['result'] ) ).map( function(val) {
  return _.object( ['name', 'value'], val );
});
```